# Java write escaped characters into file

Tags: java, file, bufferedwriter

I'm writing to a file and I need to escape some characters like a quotation mark.

```
File fout = new File("output.txt");
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fout); BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));) {
    String insert = "quote's";
    s += "'"+insert.replaceAll("'", "\\\'")+"'";
    bw.write(s.replaceAll("\r\n", "\\\r\\\n"));
    bw.newLine();
}
```

I'm trying to acheive writing `'quote\'s'` to the file but it keeps removing the backslash and producing `'quote's'`

I also want to write newlines into the file as the escaped character i.e instead of inserting a newline in file I want to write `\r\n`

Is this possible. I feel like I'm missing/forgetting something.

Comment: Change `replaceAll()` to `replace()`.

Comment: @shmosel that works! thanks. Care to detail an explanation ?

Comment: `System.out.println("Hell'o, Wor'ld!".replaceAll("'", "\\\\'"));` will print `Hell\'o, Wor\'ld!`

Comment: replaceAll handle regular expression. Including the replace part, as example `System.out.println("Hello!".replaceAll("(ll)", "$1o$1"));`  this will result `Hellollo!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) works with regex and accepts a special replacement syntax:

> Note that backslashes (`\`) and dollar signs (`$`) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string

You're not using regex, so you can use the plaintext [`replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) instead. And you only need 2 backslashes at a time:

```
s += "'"+insert.replace("'", "\\'")+"'";
bw.write(s.replace("\r\n", "\\r\\n"));
```

Comment: you do not need `"\\\'"`, instead use `\\'`

Comment: That's true, single quotes don't have to be escaped.

Comment: OP says "instead of inserting a newline in file I want to write `\r\n`". But your code does not.